# How to reduce the size of the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with almost 2,000 DOM elements (nodes), which includes, among other things, a simple table with over 200 links to other subpages:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul><li><a href="#tabs-1" >Al-Ar</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2" >Ar-D</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3" >E-Ha</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4" >Ha-J</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-5" >K-Mo</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-6" >Mo-Ro</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-7" >Ro-So</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-8" >So-Su</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-9" >Su-Z</a></li></ul>
<table class="tablica_hoteli">
<tbody>
<tr class="tr1"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="tr"><td>
<div id="tabs-1">
<table class="pol">
<tbody>
<tr> <td class="td10" colspan="4">Al..Ar</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="1.html">1</a></td>
<td class="td2">1</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="2.html">2</a></td>
<td class="td2">2</td></tr>
...
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="20.html">20</a></td>
<td class="td2">20</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="pol">
<tbody>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="21.html">21</a></td>
<td class="td2">21</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="21.html">21</a></td>
<td class="td2">21</td></tr>
...
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="30.html">30</a></td>
<td class="td2">30</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<table class="pol">
<tbody>
<tr> <td class="td10" colspan="4">Ar...</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="31.html">31</a></td>
<td class="td2">31</td></tr>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="32.html">32</a></td>
<td class="td2">32</td></tr>
...
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="51.html">51</a></td>
<td class="td2">51</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="pol">
<tbody>
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="52.html">52</a></td>
<td class="td2">52</td></tr>
...
<tr> <td class="td1"><a href="205.html">205</a></td>
<td class="td2">205</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</tr>
<tr class="tr1"><td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The start page only shows "# tabs-1", and the rest of the pages have to be clicked later to view. So the rest of the content from "# tabs-2" to "# tabs-9" does not need to load.
What's the easiest way to optimize the DOM size? How do I get the rest of the # tabs-2 "code to not load on startup?
I don't know how to do it and that's why I am asking for help.

Oh, maybe it would be helpful to know that the table is written with jQuery

Comment: This feels like focussing on the wrong thing: DOM parsing is _super fast_ and HTML data is _super tiny_, so what actual problem do you think this solves? Because it's not load time, and it's not transfer time. HTML like this is in fact infinitely better than anything JS related, because the moment it's in your browser _it already works_, no JS required, it's all there, in the blink of an eye.

Comment: can you provide a gist of the jQuery code which is generating this HTML? & explaining who do you want the table behave to lazy-load its resources?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the code from:

```
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax
```

> plus links to jQuery sites:

```
jquery.min.js,
jquery-ui.min.js,
jquery.lazyload.min.js
```

And I mean position in Lighthouse where I can see in Diagnostics "Avoid an excessive DOM size" = 1956 nodes.
And I would like to reduce this value, this means that only the first page should be loaded